# Set default schema and migration table schema in same place?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to set the default schema for a context somewhere in `AddDbContext` or somewhere else when configuring services?

I'd like to be able to set the schema for the migration table and the rest of the database in the same place, and *Startup.cs* seems to be the most likely candidate. I thought maybe I could write a `IDbContextOptionsExtension`, and the extension gets added (I can see it from the `DbContextOptions` constructor of my context), but I can't figure out how to get at the `ModelBuilder`. If I create an `IModelCustomizer`, I can't figure out how to get at the extension from `ModelCustomizerDependencies`, `ModelBuilder`, or `DbContext`. Thoughts?

I have possibility of a small number of simple code-first contexts needing to create tables in existing databases, and being able to set up the schema in one place would be nice. (These contexts only ever use one schema.)

Thoughts? Thanks!